# Python Console Chessboard checkering not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, chess

I want to make a 8×8 chessboard with 3×3 for each tile in Python. But there are problems with the checkering. I can't really show what it prints out, so you will have to run it yourself. Here is my code:

```
print("""
Chess

Press Enter to Start...
""")

enterwait= input()
if enterwait= "":
    line = []
    chessboard = ""
    changeColorAllowed = False
    lineQueue = False
    queue = 0
    
    for linecount in range(24):
        for i in range(24):
            
            if i%3==0:
                changeColorAllowed = not changeColorAllowed

                
            if changeColorAllowed == False:
                if linecount%3==0 or linecount%4==0 or linecount%5==0:
                    line.append([queue,"white", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
                else:
                    line.append([queue,"black", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
                    
            else:
                if linecount%3==0 or linecount%4==0 or linecount%5==0:
                    line.append([queue,"black", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
                else:
                    line.append([queue,"white", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])


    for i in line:
        if len(chessboard)%25==0:
            chessboard+="\n"
        if i[1] == "white":
            chessboard += "⬜"
        else: 
            chessboard += "⬛"
        
            
    print(chessboard)
```

Any help is appreciated!

bad checkering on my python chessboard

Comment: `if linecount%3==0 or linecount%4==0 or linecount%5==0:` That condition is True if `linecount` is any of 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21. Seems like an unusual pattern - is it really what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `if linecount%3==0 or linecount%4==0 or linecount%5==0` makes little sense. There is nothing in this grid that repeats every 4 or 5 lines.

The body of the first nested loops, that populates `line`, can be fixed with this body:

```
        if (linecount // 3) % 2 == (i // 3) % 2:
            line.append([queue,"white", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
        else:
            line.append([queue,"black", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
```

But you can do the whole chessboard with much less code, making use of the `*` operator on strings and lists:

```
line = "⬜⬜⬜⬛⬛⬛" * 4
chessboard = "\n".join(([line] * 3 + [line[::-1]] * 3) * 4)
print(chessboard)
```

Comment: Do you also know how to find the middle square for each 3×3 tile? If possible, please help

Comment: When `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the chess square, where each is a number between 0 and 7, then the corresponding center character is at index `26 + x * 3 + y * 75` of `chessboard`. If you cannot make it work, please ask a new question.